# Find the location of multiple strings in a cell array of strings

Tags: string, matlab

I have 2 question regarding searching for strings in MATLAB

1. If I have to find a string in a cell array of strings I can do the following to get the location of `'PO'` in the cell array

   ```
   find(strcmpi({'PO','FOO','PO1','FOO1','PO1','PO'},'PO'))
   %   1   6
   ```

   But, I really want to search for multiple strings (`{'PO1', 'PO'}`) at the same time (not using a for loop). What is the best way to do this?
2. Is there any function like `histc()` which can tell me how many times the string has occurred. Again for one string, I could do:

   ```
   length(strfind({'PO','FOO','PO1','FOO1','PO1','PO'},'PO'))
   ```

   But this obviously doesn't work for multiple strings at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find multiple strings, then just use the second output of `ismember` instead to tell you which string it is. If you really need case-insensitive matching, I've added the `upper` call to force all inputs to be upper-case. You can omit this if you think it's already uppercase.

```
data = {'PO','FOO','PO1','FOO1','PO1','PO', 'PO'};

[tf, inds] = ismember(upper(data), {'PO1', 'PO'});
%   2     0     1     0     1     2     2
```

You can then use the second output to determine which string was found where:

```
% PO1 Occurrences
find(inds == 1)
%   3   5

% PO Occurrences
find(inds == 2)
%   1   6   7
```

If you want the equivalent of `histc`, you can use `accumarray` to do that. We can pass it all of the values of `inds` that are non-zero (i.e. the ones that you were actually searching for).

```
accumarray(inds(tf).', ones(sum(tf), 1))
%   2   3
```

If instead you want to get the histogram of *all* strings (not just the ones you're searching for) you could do the following:

```
[strings, ~, inds] = unique(data, 'stable');
occurrences = accumarray(inds, ones(size(inds)));

%   'PO'      [3]
%   'FOO'     [1]
%   'PO1'     [2]
%   'FOO1'    [1]
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help , Your replies are always great and very helpful ! ismember() was my first approach but I was confused with how to use indices actually but now I have realized